# ActiveMQConsumer.receive(1000) returns null

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

We are putting message into `ACtiveMQ`, we are running sample program with this method `ActiveMessageConsumer.receive(1000)` always returns `null` message.
Even though Queue has messages, still not able to receive those messages.
    url = "http://" ;

```
connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "xxxxx", url);

connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
((ActiveMQConnection)connection).getPrefetchPolicy().setQueuePrefetch(0);
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

destination = session.createQueue("something.sampleQ");
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
ActiveMQObjectMessage message = (ActiveMQObjectMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
```

Comment: We are running above program in while loop still getting same null response

Answer (score 0):

Your ActiveMQ URL should be one of these: 
http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html

For example: tcp://localhost:61616

Comment: No, we can use even http/https also, with that it was working but now with 5.12.3 it is not working.

Comment: Ok, I see - you use the HTTP tunnel URI with "http://host:port". I guess you verified your queue name and how exactly do you see messages inside the ActiveMQ ?

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6823

there is bug with AMQ 5.12.3 which is resolved with 5.15.1 for http connector